# Checking whether input is 5,10,15,20,25 or 30 in java

Tags: java, error-handling

JAVA CODE:

I'm trying to check when someone inputs a 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, or 30.
It's a mortgage calculate, and this is the amortization period, but I also need it to loop
and error check. If the person inputs anything but 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, or 30, it has to say:

"Please input either 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, or 30."

And loop and wait for input again.

I know you can check with an if statement for each int, but I'm not sure how to loop 
this statement.

Comment: Take a look at [The while and do-while statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Answer (score 3):

`if(x%5==0)` returns `true` if `x` is a multiple of 5.

`if(x>0)` returns `true` if `x` is greater than 0.

`if(x<31)` returns `true` if `x` is less than 31.

You can combine these checks with the `&&` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean test;
do {
    int x = input;//read input
    test = (x%5 == 0 && x > 0 && x <= 30);
    if(!test) {
        System.out.println("Please input either 5,10,15,20,25 or 30.");
    }
} while(!test);
```

Input is probably something like:

```
sc.nextInt();
```

when you use a `Scanner` on `System.in`:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);//put this code somewhere before entering the do-while loop.
```

Comment: You shouldn't just dump answers on people who haven't put any effort in themselves.

Comment: I agree, but I don't see why this is a reason to downvote this answer :(.

Comment: Because in the long run you aren't really helping OP,  you didn't even give any explanation either.

Comment: I disagree given the answer I gave. I wouldn't dump the answer when it's a question about algorithmic. But simple text-based I/O-questions in general are asked by people having no clue about how I/O should be done. Before I knew the `Scanner`-class, IO was a hell. By simply providing one solution, the OP can learn how to use a class like this.

Comment: Well then we can agree to disagree.

Comment: Actually, this isn't a point of disagreement, redFIVE. You are simply wrong: "Don't downvote others who answer homework questions in good faith." Found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Furthermore as a teaching assistant at KU Leuven I can say if we would refuse such simple questions we would receive quite negative feedback at the end of the academic year...

Comment: Indeed, the kid is trying, and if he doesn't really learn, he will bite it on the exam. Anyway, it's wrong for redFIVE or anyone to abuse community features to impose his personal worldview.

Comment: @CommuSoft The options are more than simply "give complete answer" or "refuse question".  There's an alternate option, something like the "answer" I provided, which gives a real big hint toward the complete answer without doing the student's homework for them.

Answer (score 0):

a perfect candidate to use a do while loop:

```
    int tries = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x;
    do {
             tries ++;
             if ( tries < MAX_TRIES) {
            System.out.print("Please input either 5,10,15,20,25 or 30.");
            x = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println(); 


         } else {
              System.out.println("maybe you can't use a keyboard.");
              break;
        }
       }while ( ! (x%5 == 0 && x > 0 && x <=30);
```

basically this is just saying, keep reading x until that condition is true.
`x > 0 && x <=30` gives the numbers between 1 and 30 and `x%5 == 0`  filter out numbers which are not a multiple of 5

Comment: I'm not expert with `Scanner`, but I believe if `nextInt` fails (because the user entered a non-integer value), it will continue trying to read from the stream and put you into an infinite loop...